# Use Team Foundation Service and Git Support from Monodevelop

Tags: tfs, monodevelop

**NOTE: This question was asked before the release of git support in the TFS Service, and this works quite well now. Read more about using tfs service with monodevelop here: http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.se/2013/02/how-to-use-team-foundation-service-with.html**

We decided to try out Team Foundation Service (the TFS cloud version) because it has Git support which would (we hoped) help us manage both our VisualStudio and MonoDevelop code in one place.

The question is how to connect to the TFS service in MonoDevelop? From what I can see, I should use HTTPS protocol, for server I just type the name of our TFS service, and for user I type in my live id user@live.com and try to connect.

The problem is the url which becomes something like this

`https://user@live.com@projectname.visualstudio.com/`

Note the two @ signs in the url. Seems that whatever git Tools are used behind MonoDevelop barfs on that:

`NGit.Api.Errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of fetch command ---> NGit.Errors.NotSupportedException: Invalid URL`

If I try to omit the user name from the dialog, I get another error about unauthorized access.

Is there a way to enter/store git username and password somewhere on the mac or in MonoDevelop? I'm pretty sure this would work eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Foundation Service ([`tfs.visualstudio.com`](http://tfs.visualstudio.com), formerly `tfspreview.com`) does not host git repositories, only Team Foundation Server repositories.

It sounds like you may be conflating two different concepts:

- Codeplex, Microsoft's hosting site for open source software, does support [both TFS and git hosting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeplex/archive/2012/03/21/git-commit-m-codeplex-now-supports-git.aspx), as well as Mercurial.
- Microsoft recently announced the [git-tf](http://gittf.codeplex.com/) project that allows you to create a local git repository that tracks a remote Team Foundation Server repository.

git-tf was designed with cross-platform users in mind, who [use an IDE that does not have native support for Team Foundation Server source code control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ethomson/archive/2012/08/20/team-foundation-server-and-xcode-projects-with-git-tf.aspx).  It sounds like using git-tf would probably be the most applicable for you.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that the "git-tf" stuff was the real thing, but as you write, it's not :( At least I can "commit" from within MonoDevelop and use the "git tf" command line tool to checkin and pull, so it's better than nothing!

Comment: UPDATE: tfs.visualstudio.com now [hosts Git repositories](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/home/news/2013/jan-30/#git%20support)

Comment: @JamesFernandes: Indeed.  When I read this question back in December I was truly terrified that we had accidentally switched git on for the public.  :)

Comment: lol, sorry about that :) so now it should actuallu work? I need to read up and test :)